# Using an Array of Class Instances in multiple source files

Tags: c++, arrays, instances

I am trying to access an array of class instances from two source files, was hoping you could point me in the right direction. Here's roughly what I have so far.

```
//X.h    
extern Object myObj[5];

//A.cpp
#include X.h

Object myObj[5];

myObj[0].doSomething();
...
myObj[4].doSomething();


//B.cpp   
#include X.h

Object myObj[5];

myObj[0].doSomethingElse();
...
myObj[4].doSomethingElse();
```

I have entirely no idea if I am along the right lines. Even a phrase or two for me to google would be much appreciated.

Comment: Statements such as `myObj[0].doSomething();` can't go outside of functions. But other than that, maybe describe the problems you're having?

Comment: I believe you'd end up with multiple definitions of `myObj`. It should be defined only once.

Comment: Avoid global/static variables to pass stuff around! Rethink your design thoroghly!!

Comment: @juanchopanza Those statements are inside functions I was just trying to generalise in a way that didn't involve typing all the code. The problem I'm having is that everything compiles fine, but doesn't run how I want, I believe I have two separate arrays, because when I put `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` together just for testing it works fine. However it's imperative to have them separate due to a lot of other code. What I'm trying to do is get the `myObj.doSomethignElse` that's in `B.cpp` to affect the array declared in `A.cpp`

Comment: @mnunberg  I do end up with multiple definitions but can't find a way that I Can only define it once where it still compiles

Comment: Pick either `A.cpp` or `B.cpp` to "host" the definition.

Comment: @GeorgeV You need only 1 `extern Object myObj[5]` and 1 `Object myObj[5]`.

Comment: You should try posting some minimal code that reproduces the problem you care about, not some code which generates *other* problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The usage of extern in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841495/the-usage-of-extern-in-c)

Comment: @mnunberg @Chnossos when the definition is in only one source file (A.cpp), I get a `variable undefined` error when compiling, pointing to the line in B.cpp where the `myObj.doSomethingElse()` is.

Comment: @GeorgeV 'variable undefined' won't happen if you properly #include the extern. Your attempt to show what you have is full of misleading elements - show the real thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a pointer to the array. so int file "A"

```
Object arr[5];

Object* GetArr(){
   return &arr;
}
```

and file "B"

```
#include "a.cpp"
void DoSomething(){
    Object* pArr = GetArr();
    //use pArr
}
```

That may work for your situation.
Good Luck

Comment: Your answer put me on the right track. I ended up with:
   Object * arr[5] = new Object[5];
   Object** GetArr()
   {
       return &arr;
   }
then using it like this

   Object** arrB = GetArr();

Comment: That's the same principle just with one extra layer of pointers. So good, I'm glad I could help .